# How to post to LinkedIn "Share" with node-auth?

Tags: node.js, oauth, express

This is what I have, but LinkedIn returns "unauthorized" error back:

```
var OAuth= require('oauth').OAuth;

oa= new OAuth("https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken",
    "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken",
    "key",  "secret", "1.0A", "http://test.com/oauth/callback", "HMAC-SHA1");

var post_data = {
share: {
   "comment":"testing 123",
   "visibility": {
    "code":"anyone"
   }
}
};

oa.post("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?twitter-post=true", oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, post_data, 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', function(error, data){
 }
```

Appreciate any help. The oauth_token and oauth_token_secret works when fetching resources, so I think they are correct.

Regards,

Johnny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth) which is built on oauth and supports LinkedIn. It takes cares of all the authentication and it is configured easily. After the configuration, the client will be authenticated by a link like `/oauth/linkedin` and after authentication you can have the tokens in express routes.

Answer (score 0):

have u got permission for sharing? u have to gain access scope for rw_nus
check in [linkedIn REST API for share](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api#toggleview%3aid=xml)