# LinkedIn API oauth issues with sending message node.js

Tags: node.js, api, linkedin-api

I have this same issue:

[How to post to LinkedIn "Share" with node-auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729065/how-to-post-to-linkedin-share-with-node-auth)

Essentially I am using the linkedin-js NPM module which works great with GET requests. I am using the module in conjuncture with passport and am successfully generating the oauth token and secret. When POST did not work for messaging I went into the oauth dependency library and changed all the Content-Type headers to application/json and the X-li-format headers to json. Also, all my other bases are covered. I have "w_messages" set in scope and other requests are working.

I do not really need the x-li-format header since I have the application/json header. The only thing I can think of is that the access tokens are off (perhaps a step I am missing - this is unlikely since all other requests requiring authentication work) or the plaintext signature is thrown off by application/json Content-Type (following error is not thrown):

```
  if( signatureMethod != "PLAINTEXT" && signatureMethod != "HMAC-SHA1")
throw new Error("Un-supported signature method: " + signatureMethod )
```

I went from this error message:

```
{ statusCode: 401,
data: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\n<error>\n  <status>401</status>\n  <timestamp>1375876823051</timestamp>\n  
<request-id>0WFU40UZP8</request-id>\n  <error-code>0</error-code>\n  <message>[unauthorized]. OAU:fgb949d9gb66|427a55ea-a05e-4494-88f5-a33230bd719a|*01|*01:1375876915:WWqVTAe9WQneEf8ezL6Yl7DMyV4=</message>\n</error>\n' }
```

To this error message:

```
{ statusCode: 401,
data: '{\n  "errorCode": 0,\n  "message": "[unauthorized]. 
OAU:fgb949d9gb66|ce1f124c-1e10-4abc-8777-55bbd9621100|*01|*01:1375913097:EH90Q69mhGRwiCVcknimzAUnLqI=",\n  
"requestId": "KOYHE8K0M6",\n  "status": 401,\n  "timestamp": 1375913004009\n}' }
```

Here is the api call and corresponding oauth calls:

```
linkedinClient.apiCall('POST', '/people/~/mailbox',
    {
        "token": {
            "oauth_token_secret": tokenSecret
            , "oauth_token": token
        },
        "mailbox-item": {"recipients": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "person": {
                        "_path": people,
                    }
                }]
        },
        "subject": subject,
        "body": body}
    }
    , function (error, result) {
        if (result){
            req.io.emit('success', {success : "LinkedIn message sent successfully."});
        }
        console.log(error);
    }
);

var CLIENT = {
oauth: new OAuth(
  'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken'
, 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken'
, key
, secret
, '1.0A'
, redirect
, 'HMAC-SHA1'
, null
, {'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'close', 'X-li-format': 'json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
)
}

CLIENT.oauth.post(
    _rest_base + path
  , token.oauth_token
  , token.oauth_token_secret
  , params
  , 'application/json'
  , requestCallback(callback)
  );
```

Comment: You need to provide a lot more info. What errors are you getting?

Comment: I just updated with errors.